# Thread that create more Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know how to stop threads created by one "father" thread in a code like this.

```
public class HiloEspecie extends Thread{
    private Especie especie;
    private Procreador pro;

    public HiloEspecie(Especie especie, Procreador pro){
        this.especie = especie;
        this.pro = pro;
    }


    public void run() {
        while(!pro.isEmpty()){
            pro.procrear(especie.getIcon(), especie.getTiempoReproduccion());
            HiloEspecie hijo = new HiloEspecie(especie, pro);
            hijo.start();
        }

    }
}
```

/* can you tell me if I need an array for the "hijo" threads. or maybe a threadPool in order to stop them after, or how can I stop them

/* Edit::
thank you for all the tips you gave me, I actually manage to solve it using ThreadGroup, java automatically assign the same ThreadGroup to a Thread that was created by other thread, so all I need to do is create and assign a new ThreadGroup to the "Father" Thread and then all his "sons" are included by default in the same ThreadGroup, finally doing (carefully) (ThreadGroup)xxyy.stop();  will stop all the threads including "father" thread.

Comment: You could have a `ThreadGroup`.

Comment: You should not stop threads from the top level but let the Threads know that they should kill themselves by setting a readable `flag` in the parent class.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - Or by using `Thread.interrupt()` and `Thread.isInterrupted()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java language does not recognize any parent/child relationship between threads, but it does have something that might help you:  Read about the `java.lang.ThreadGroup` class.

Every thread is a member of a thread group, and you can `interrupt()` a ThreadGroup.  If your threads all are designed to stop when interrupted, and if they are all members of the same ThreadGroup, then you can stop them all by interrupting the ThreadGroup.

Answer (score 5):

You need a reference to the thread, then you can do "something" to stop it. For example, store them in a list or array.

Note that you shouldn't call the `Thread.stop()` method - you should simply interrupt the thread, and implement the thread in such a way as to respond to interruption by stopping what it is doing as quickly as it can do safely.

---

A cleaner alternative would be to delegate thread management to an `ExecutorService`, e.g. `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads)`: when you submit a `Runnable` or `Callable` to an `ExecutorService`, you get back a `Future`, which you can cancel if you want.

You still need to write the `Runnable` or `Callable` to check for interruption if you want the task to end early, and cancel it with `future.cancel(true)`.

This means you are "cancelling tasks", rather than "stopping threads". The distinction is subtle; `Future`s are just a bit higher-level and nicer to work with. For one thing, you avoid the overhead of creating a new thread for each of the sub-tasks, as the same thread is reused.

But you'd still need to store the references to the `Future`s, e.g. in an array or list.

Comment: ExecutorService is definitely the way to go

Comment: If you use an ExecutorService, the tasks submitted to it should either be very short or be responsive to interruption to have tasks end prematurely

Comment: @bowmore in exactly the same way as "raw thread" task need to be very short or responsive to interruption if you them to end prematurely.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Your answer didn't highlight this very clearly, I felt. The "A cleaner alternative" phrasing seemed to pit ExecutorService vs. interruption.

Comment: @bowmore added a bit about interruption with the `ExecutorService`.